# React-Leaflet-Draw: accessing a polygon's array of coordinates on save

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw, react-leaflet

I've got a component which puts an editable polygon on the map. When the user hits the "save" button, I want to access an array of the polygon's new vertices, so that I can save them.  How do I do this?

**My component:**

```
<FeatureGroup>
    <EditControl
        position="topright"
        onEdited={e => console.log(e)}
        edit={{ remove: false }}
        draw={{
                marker: false,
                circle: false,
                rectangle: false,
                polygon: false,
                polyline: false
             }}
        />
        <Polygon positions={polygonCoords} />;
</FeatureGroup>
```

The couple of references I've got:

https://github.com/alex3165/react-leaflet-draw

https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event-draw:editstop

I understand I have to implement some sort of function dealing with the onEdited hook and the event generated thereby, but does anyone have any idea how I can get the new vertex array from this event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this, here's a working solution with ES6:

```
        <FeatureGroup>
            <EditControl
                position="topright"

                //this is the necessary function. It goes through each layer
                //and runs my save function on the layer, converted to GeoJSON 
                //which is an organic function of leaflet layers.

                onEdited={e => {
                    e.layers.eachLayer(a => {
                        this.props.updatePlot({
                            id: id,
                            feature: a.toGeoJSON()
                        });
                    });
                }}
                edit={{ remove: false }}
                draw={{
                    marker: false,
                    circle: false,
                    rectangle: false,
                    polygon: false,
                    polyline: false
                }}
            />
            <Polygon positions={[positions(this.props)]} />;
        </FeatureGroup>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting this took me some hours so it might be helpful to someone someday.
First initialise mapLayer state to hold your coordinates and implement onCreated() and onEdited() functions

```
        const [mapLayers, setMapLayers] = useState([]);
    
        const onCreated = e => {
            console.log(e)
    
            const {layerType, layer} = e
            if (layerType === "polygon") {
                const {leaflet_id} = layer
    
                setMapLayers(layers => [...layers, {id: leaflet_id, latlngs: layer.getLatLngs()[0]}])
            }
        };
    
        const onEdited = e => {
            // console.log('Edited data', e);
    
            const {layers: {_layers}} = e;
            Object.values(_layers).map((
                {_leaflet_id, editing}) => {
                setMapLayers((layers) => layers.map((l)  => l.id === _leaflet_id? {...l, latlngs: {...editing.latlngs[0]}
                } : l)
                )
            });
        };
```